# Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am having this error for several weeks now, and I do not know how to fix it. Similar solutions on Stack Overflow do not suit to my project.

I am currently using a mysql database, but encounter this problem whenever trying to start the server: **StackTrace**

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project iPbackend: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.resource.iPbackend.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

I am using this mainController:
**MainController.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import com.resource.iPbackend.UserRepository;
import com.resource.iPbackend.User;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/main")
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/reg", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String regNewUser (@RequestParam String firstName,      @RequestParam String lastName, @RequestParam String email, @RequestParam String password, @RequestParam String username) {
        User n = new User();
        n.setFirstName(firstName);
        n.setLastName(lastName);
        n.setEmail(email);
        n.setPassword(password);
        n.setUsername(username);
        userRepository.save(n);
        return "User is stored in database: " + n;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/all")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Together with this repository:
**UserRepository.java**

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.resource.iPbackend.User;


@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

And this Entity:
**User.java**

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String username;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

Comment: You does not have any class implement interface `UserRepository` so that the `@AutoWired` can not init a instance when you using it in the controller

Comment: @TuyenNguyen the repository is handled as a special case because it is annotated with `@Repostory`

Comment: Check that your config (either Java or XML based) is component scanning or declaring the beans you are trying to autowire.

Comment: Please show your configuration.

Comment: Its more than a special case. The @Repository annotation does nothing. These beans are registered automatically by Spring Data they are not picked up by component scanning but by enabling your JPA repositories.

Comment: Check for component scan package if the repository class is included in the package

Comment: Is it a springboot app. If so move all packages under the package of class annotated with @SpringBootApplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the annotation @EnableJpaRepositories in your base configuration class in order for Spring Data to register interfaces extending CrudRepository as spring beans.

Also the annotation @Repository does nothing on interfaces so this is not needed but it won't break anything by being there either.

**EDIT:**

You can also try and be more specific by telling the @EnableJpaRepositories annotation exactly where your repositories are. i.e.:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.resource.iPbackened")
```

Comment: All of that did not work. I am not really sure though, what my Config Class is. I have this one:

Comment: @justus I've edited my answer with some more details

Comment: @justus if that doesn't work it would be good to see your project structure as well as the base Spring Boot config class (the one annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` or `@EnableAutoConfiguration`)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Springboot (@**SpringBootApplication**) then:

Try moving all your component classes in the same(or child) packages relative to your base Springboot config class.

For Instance:

I configured my SpringBoot base config class in package **com.application**
;

And I moved **UserRepository**(you mentioned) in package **com.application.resource.iPbackend.User** it worked for me without changing anything on the Annotation side. I got no error.

Since you havent shared the your Springboot Configuration so I am assuming you will be using defaults. If solution doesnt work, pl share your spring boot config which I can try on my side and respond.

Hope this helps!